# Process, thread closing application

Tags: java, multithreading, process

i have a little application who are displayed in the system tray.

From this application i start a command,  i run another java program and i get it inputStream and display it in a textArea.

```
final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( runCommand );

input = new LoggingThread( process.getInputStream() );
error = new LoggingThread( process.getErrorStream() );

input.start();
error.start();

In loggingThread
public void run()
{

    while ( running )
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( inputStream ) );
            String line = "";
            try
            {
                while ( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null && running )
                {
                    JTextAreaAppender.getTextArea().append( line );
                    JTextAreaAppender.getTextArea().append( System.getProperty( "line.separator" ) );
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException ioe )
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

when i quit application i do

```
input.setRunning(false);
error.setRunning(false);
```

i do also a dispose on the TrayIcon class

in the task manager, i continue to see two thread for the application, and one for Process

if i remove process, thread... application is closing correctly

if i put

```
proc.destroy();
```

after setRunning, closing application don't work at all, TrayIcon continue to display

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> when i quit application i do
>
> input.setRunning(false);
>
> error.setRunning(false);
>
> i do also a dispose on the TrayIcon class
>
> in the task manager, i continue to see two thread for the application, and one for Process

No need to do that. If you want to close your applications even if some threads are still executing, you can mark them as daemons. Just place these lines after the threads declarations.

```
input.setDaemon(true);
error.setDaemon(true);
```

> [Thread#setDaemon(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29)
>
> Marks this thread as either a daemon thread or a user thread. The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.
>   This method must be invoked before the thread is started.